# Solve differentials equations using the Fourier transform and convolution theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-transform, convolution

So I have the two following exercises :

1) Solve the following differential equation :
$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}u(x,y)+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}u(x,y)=0$$

where $x\in \mathbb{R}$, $y > 0$

knowing that $u(x,0)=h(x)$ where $h: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is an absolute, integrable, continuous function.

Hint: use the Fourier transform and the convolution theorem. Keep in mind for the solution of the system that $u(\cdot,y)$ should be bounded (german :beschränkt).

2) Let $\alpha>0$. Solve

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}u(t,x)=\alpha^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}u(t,x)$$

$t>0$, $x\in \mathbb{R}$

knowing that $u(x,0)=h(x)$ where $h: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is an absolute, integrable, continuous function.

My attempt : For the first one, I tried to transform both sides. So I wrote
$$(-2\pi if_1)^2U(f_1,f_2)+(-2\pi if_2)^2U(f_1,f_2)=0$$

($f$ is the frequency)

Now, I know about the convolution theorem : $$F(f\cdot g) = F(f)*F(g)$$ (where $*$ denotes the convolution) and I have an initial condition, but I don't really see how to proceed. I also looked on the internet, but I didn't really find a lot of help.

For the second one, I suppose the method to proceed is similar.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: B as in Beschränkt.. hmm where have I seen it... :) Anyway you need one frequency variable for each variable which has partial derivatives on them. You can call them $f_1, f_2$ or $u,v$ or something third. Just make sure you know which is $x$ frequency, which is $y$ frequency and which is $t$ frequency and don't mix them up.

Comment: Why would Fourier transform in $x$ and then in $y$ yield the same one variable frequency function? Should be something like $\mathcal{F}_x \left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}u(x,y)\right)) = (-2\pi i f_1)^2 U(f_1,f_2)$ and something along $\mathcal{F}_y \left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial u^2}u(x,y)\right) =  g(f_1,f_2)$. Remember $y>0$ so if you put up the integral you would get $\int_{0}^{\infty}...$ and not $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}...$ as in the case when transforming in $x$.